# dataTables and sorting by date in IE8

Tags: sorting, datatables

Having some trouble having [dataTables](http://datatables.net/) sort date fields (which have `{"sType":"date"}`. The `null` sorting type (which just sorts the data as if it's a plain string) works fine in IE8.

Works in IE 9 & 10, as well as latest versions of Chrome, Safari, Firefox. This app is not used on mobile clients, so I didn't test it there.

Is there something special about IE8 that I need to be looking into? There are no errors on the JavaScript console in IE8, so I'm a little stumped as to where to look. Checked the [dataTables](http://datatables.net/) docs and search around SO, but have yet to find anything IE8-specific.

**UPDATE:**

Here's the JavaScript I'm using to initialize my datatable.

```
//sprv results table
$("#sprv_report_table").livequery(function(){$(this).dataTable({
  "aoColumns": [{"sType":"date"},null,null,null,null,{"sType":"date"}],
  "iDisplayLength": 10, 
  "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
});});1
```

Since the datatables code does get applied to the table, and I can sort other columns, I don't have any reason to believe that this event isn't getting fired - it seems rather obvious that it is being fired by the browser.

Comment: What's the behavior in IE8 when you try to sort on the date column? Are you using US-style MM/dd/yyyy dates?

Comment: It highlights the column, but the order of the table entries does not change. I just realized that I'm several versions back (1.7.4), so I'm going to investigate that angle first.

Comment: So, it turns out that even the latest version of datatables has the same problem. I've updated my question with the javascript I'm using to initialize my datatable.

Comment: What's the HTML look like in that column? I guess I still suspect whatever date format you're using is "non-standard". I'd be inclined to use a custom mData for sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(this).dataTable({
  "aoColumns": [{
    mData: function(data, type) {
       var realDate = Date.parse(data); //data will be a string
       switch(type) {
         case 'display':
            return realDate.toString('MM/dd/yyyy'); //note that this line needs to be implemented by you (however you format dates)
         default:
            return realDate;
       }
    }
   },null,null,null,null,{"sType":"date"}],
  "iDisplayLength": 10, 
  "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
});
```

See reference on `mData` usage here: http://datatables.net/ref

> integer - treated as an array index for the data source. This is the default that DataTables uses (incrementally increased for each column).
>
> string - read an object property from the data source. Note that you can use Javascript dotted notation to read deep properties / arrays from the data source.
>
> null - the sDefaultContent option will be used for the cell (null by default, so you will need to specify the default content you want - typically an empty string). This can be useful on generated columns such as edit / delete action columns.
>
> **function - the function given will be executed whenever DataTables needs to set or get the data for a cell in the column. The function takes three parameters:
>   {array|object} The data source for the row
>   {string} The type call data requested - this will be 'set' when setting data or 'filter', 'display', 'type', 'sort' or undefined when gathering data. Note that when undefined is given for the type DataTables expects to get the raw data for the object back**
>
> {*} Data to set when the second parameter is 'set'.
>
> The return value from the function is not required when 'set' is the type of call, but otherwise the return is what will be used for the data requested.

Comment: So, basically take the date and custom sort it with a hand-written function. I'll give that a shot, as I'm running into other quirks, and that may be the most straight forward approach that hopefully will not have different side effects on different browsers.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm trying to help you avoid. DataTables /will/ sort a real date object (e.g.`realDate instanceof Date`). DataTables runs the mData function at sort time, so it'll know to compare the data _as dates_, not as "strings-that-look-like-dates"

Comment: Ah, I see, and I see the distinction between sorting dates vs. strings that look like dates. Forgive my ongoing naivety, but it seems like I could replace the function above with `mData: function(data, type) { return Date.parse(data); }` - as my experiments show that the 'display' case isn't necessary. What am I missing in that approach?

Comment: @normalocity: Not a thing really. Just when it renders that date that's being returned, it'll probably be some ugly format you won't like (e.g. `Fri Mar 15 2013 15:33:09 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)`), that's why I (generally) split my `display` case into a separate case (redundancy....sorry). But that's really up to you. What you posted will definitely work.

Comment: To clarify: DataTables just does a `.toString()` on the returned value (if I recall correctly), so that's the reason for the ugly returned value and why I suggested some sort of formatting. If you'd like a suggestion in that regard, I use this daily and it's quite robust even though it hasn't been updated in a while. Uses .NET style formatting rules http://www.masterdata.se/r/string_format_for_javascript/

Comment: Gotcha. In my case it seems to be getting its formatting from somewhere else, because I'm working with this sorting problem in two places, each of which use different date display formatting, and each of which retain said formatting even with the simplified patch. For now I think I'm okay on the display side. Thanks a lot - really helped!