# Datatable sorting issue in IE working fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have column with String type but it holding the value of time in this format dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss. When i do sorting its working fine in chrome. But in IE its not working.  Please could you help us to resolve this issue?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  dataTestTable = $('#programListId').DataTable(
    {
      "bPaginate": false,
      "bLengthChange": false,
      "bFilter": true,
      "bInfo": false,
      "bSort": true,
      "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
      "order": [[12, "desc"]],
      "paging": true,
      "columnDefs": [
          {"targets": 0, "render": $.fn.dataTable.render.ellipsis(12, true)},

      ],
    }
  );

  testTable = dataTestTable;
}
```

Below code also not working for Sorting

```
 "columnDefs": [
   {"targets": 12, "type":'Date'},
   ...
 ]
```

Comment: See if that does not solve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437482/datatables-and-sorting-by-date-in-ie8 or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769121/datatables-date-sorting-not-working-on-firefox-ie

Comment: Hi Both the links not having solution for format dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.Please could you provide proper solution

Comment: Add the complete code related to the problem.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this post (https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18). IF that doesn't help work up a simple JSFiddle and we can take a look in greater depth. What version of IE are you having an issue with?